# Add breakpoints in every function I have defined. (visual studio 2010/2012, c++)

Tags: c++, breakpoints

I'm reading source codes of a huge project.Some functions are encapsulated in dlls.
So I want to add breakpoints before every functions defined in codes,in order to follow the process of this project by F5 and avoid the disassembly window show on visual studio.
There are thousands functions in codes, I can't add every breakpoints by manual work.Is there any method or add-in to help me to do this work?
Tks!

Comment: Can't you just turn off the disassembly window?

Answer (score 0):

Good approach in your case would be start with F10 instead of F5. And in VS you can check all calls with one break point. You should make use of call stack window provided by Visual studio. Whenever a break point will be hit, it will show the whole path from where the call was initiated. After a break point hit, the "call stack" tab will appear with other tabs at the bottom of VS like Error List, Output, Find Results.